# Problem with mu building "error while loading shared libraries: libxapian.so.30"

Tags: emacs, mu, mu4e

I just built Mu in order to read my mails in emacs with mu4e. For this I had also to install GMIME 3.0 and Xapian 1.4 who are dependencies of mu.

The build of mu didn't give any error, but when calling "mu server" in the command line I get the following error message:

```
mu: error while loading shared libraries: 
libxapian.so.30: cannot open shared object file: 
No such file or directory
```

I am on ubuntu 16.04.2. I have tried the following with no results:

- Symlinking a libxapian.so.30 to libxapian.so. When I do that I get another type of error:

  ```
  mu: symbol lookup error: mu: undefined symbol:_ZN6Xapian16WritableDatabaseC1ERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEii
  ```
- Adding to LD_LIBRARY_PATH, the path of the libxapian.so file.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't build by hand mu so I switched to installing the libraries through apt.

```
sudo apt install maildir-utils
sudo apt install mu4e
```

And adding to the loadpath the path where apt installs mu4e (emacs24/site-lisp).